# Code in xcode 6 no longer working in xcode 6.3.1

Tags: swift, xcode6.3.1

before this to delete a cell value in UItableview i use the following code and it works as it should .... but now it give me an error. THE ERROR:   **Cannot invoke 'deletedObjects' with an argument list of type '(NSManagedObject)'**
  on the following line:

```
context.deletedObjects(results[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
```

How to fix this? 
The codes in the function involved:

```
     let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")
            var appDel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
            var context = appDel.managedObjectContext
            var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserCholesterol")
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var results: NSArray = context!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        context.deletedObjects(results[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)

        context!.save(nil)
        totalEntries = totalEntries - 1
        tblLog.reloadData()
```

Comment: I very much doubt that `context.deletedObjects()` worked in previous versions of Xcode. It may have compiled, but it did not delete any objects in any Xcode/Swift version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a managed object is done with `context.deleteObject(anObject)`. Try this:

```
context.deleteObject(results[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

`deletedObjects` is just a property of `NSManagedObjectContext`,not a method.But there is a method called `- deleteObject:`.

Try to replace to this line of code:

```
context.deleteObject(results[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject) // in Xcode 6.3 and above,you have to add ! after `as` keyword.
```

Comment: thanks guys you save my day .. sometime i just want to rollback to the previous version of xcode .  i type  context!.deleteObject(results[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)    and all erros gone.  I'm very sceptical to upgrade to 6.3.2 ...